# What is ProwlerAgent?

Tags: malware

Like the asker of [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18708354/strange-bug-report-error-caused-by-prowleragent411), I'm receiving crash reports that mention something called ProwlerAgent.  Whatever ProwlerAgent is, it appears to have insinuated itself into my app's classpath:

`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.myapp.BootReceiver in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader@/system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar:/system/app/ProwlerAgent234.apk:/data/app/com.myapp-1.apk`

**I'm not asking how to fix the crash.**  I'm sure it's a problem with my app's manifest.  I'm just curious if anyone knows what ProwlerAgent is, because it seems suspicious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well prowleragant application is a norton symantec application. Haven't seen it myself and couldn't find a download link of it. This app was removed from market, and the word market suggests that it was an old application. But a part of norton it may be present in the norton antivirus for android, haven't decompiled it will do later, as soon as my pc gets in a working state. And yes you answered it correctly, and it's not a personal or other antivirus or sandbox agent. And and antivirus can implement it's structure to get activity data of the app, that suggests for the application to be checked for it's reputation, it's internet activity and data structure, so as to recognize a potential malware or a virus. Here check some links about it :

http://www.bestappsmarket.com/p/app?appId=961494&title=com-symantec-starmobile-prowler-sample

https://plus.google.com/+LitrikDeRoy/posts/cfsKZC1oCa4

https://github.com/codlab/cypherapp/issues/20